# Render a view in Rails 5 API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I generated an API-only rails app with Rails 5 via `rails new <application-name> --api`. I've decided I want to include a view for testing some things and am having issues getting a view to load.

I created a users/index.html.erb file with some text and my controller is now simply `def index; end` but there is nothing appearing when I hit the /users URL. I also tried commenting out the `# config.api_only = true` in config/application.rb but that didn't affect anything. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You don't need to uncomment `config.api_only = true` for this purpose, just inherit your controller from `ActionController::Base`, or do it in your `ApplicationController` (default for common rails generation).

Code:

1. For this controller only `YourController < ActionController::Base`
2. For all apllication `ApplicationController < ActionController::Base`

Comment: Thanks - the first point didn't work for me, but the 2nd point did. Thank you!

Comment: Strange, because i tested only first point, but anyway behavior is similar :)

Comment: Expect other gotchas with rendering html views from an API app if the html endpoint ever makes use of sessions or cookies (e.g. like with devise), as these are stripped out with API only rails.

Answer (score 2):

this is from the ActionController::Metal docs https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Metal

it says:

> ActionController::Metal by default provides no utilities for rendering >views, partials, or other responses aside from explicitly calling of >response_body=, content_type=, and status=. To add the render helpers >you’re used to having in a normal controller, you can do the following:
>
> ```
> class HelloController < ActionController::Metal
>  include AbstractController::Rendering
>  include ActionView::Layouts
>  append_view_path "#{Rails.root}/app/views"
>
>   def index
>    render "hello/index"
>   end
> end
> ```

So I've tried it myself and adding just by adding the two modules actually work just fine when using it for ActionController::API

Comment: For Rails 7, `include ActionView::Layouts` did the trick