# How to set up root route with Rails API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I created a Rails API with the `--api` flag.

I want to set up a root route with a custom HTML file.

This is my `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :pros
      resources :browsers
      resources :payment_methods
      resources :prosps
      resources :prosp_likes
      resources :prosp_comments
      resources :prosp_images
      resources :recommendations
      resources :recommendation_likes
      resources :recommendation_comments
      resources :recommendation_images      
    end
  end

  root "home#index"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

This is my `home_controller.rb`:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
        render 'home/index'
    end
end
```

This is my `views/home/index.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>hi</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

It seems to direct me to my HomeController#index method, but it is not rendering the `<h1>hi</h1>` on the browser.

This is my terminal output:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2020-08-24 21:23:18 -0500
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 0ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 104)
```

Not sure if I am doing some configuration incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For rails-6

```
class HomeController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    render render: 'home/index'
  end
end
```

For rails 5 its already answered here: [Render a view in Rails 5 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884515/render-a-view-in-rails-5-api)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to change your HomeController to use rails directly, because this will be a non-api controller:

```
require 'rails/application_controller'

class HomeController < Rails::ApplicationController
  def index
    render file: 'app/views/home/index.html'
  end
end
```

Where the path `app/views/home/index.html` is where your view are.